# text in progress bar needs relocate

Tags: css

hello i am not expert in html and css. im using django in python and i want to display some data. i make this bar with 2 numbers.
i cant place right the number: 75

im not good with my english so i cant give more details but i provide some code to get the idea

thanks for reading and understand me :)

```css
.progress {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-color: #00f !important;
  color: #fff;
  background-size: 1rem 1rem;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0.703125rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.bg-success {
  background-color: #5eba00 !important;
}
.progress-bar-striped {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-size: 1rem 1rem;
}
.progress-bar {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #467fcf;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <span class="progress">75
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="57" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%;">
      <span class="sr-only">25</span>
    </div>
  </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/zu7aq854/5/

Never place div tag inside span tag.

```
<td>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="57" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <span class="sr-only">25</span>
    </div>

    <div class="progress-bar bg-error progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="57" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <span class="sr-only">75</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

```
.progress {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-color: #00f !important;
  color: #fff;
  background-size: 1rem 1rem;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0.703125rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.bg-success {
  background-color: #5eba00 !important;
}
.progress-bar-striped {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-size: 1rem 1rem;
}
.progress-bar {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #467fcf;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.progress-bar.bg-error {
  flex-basis: 75%;
}
```

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are creating two divs in Django with almost the same template.

```css
.progress {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-color: #00f !important;
  color: #fff;
  background-size: 1rem 1rem;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0.703125rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.bg-success {
  background-color: #5eba00 !important;
}

.progress-bar-striped {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-size: 1rem 1rem;
}

.progress-bar {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #467fcf;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <span class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="57" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%;">
      <span class="sr-only">25</span>

  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-error progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="57" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%;">
    <span class="sr-only">75</span> 
  </div>
  </span>
</td>
```